# Error im receiving in Python (Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

Currently trying to construct a program with multiple windows (Main screen -> A Landlord / Customer section -> calendar/calculator ect)

I am very much a beginner at this moment in time, i keep coming across two errors:

> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\idlelib\run.py",
>   line 119, in main
>       seq, request = rpc.request_queue.get(block=True, timeout=0.05)   File
>   "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\queue.py",
>   line 172, in get
>       raise Empty queue.Empty

Also another query; a error i receive a lot is how to define "Self" ("self is not defined")

EDIT

My code is very much dis-functional -  i think looking at my code will probably give you a heart attack. When running the code i want there to be 1 screen at one time, currently 3 come up at the start, im assuming this is too me using wrong inheritance or something

It was too big to place in here so you can easily view the code here

http://textuploader.com/525p5

To be honest any help will really be appreciated. My first time doing something complex on python such as a working program with features such as a calendar, calculator ect

Cheers
Ross

Comment: Post your code. From the error message we cant really help. A broken code is much better then no code at all

Comment: The stacktrace seems to suggest the exception happens in IDLE, not your code. Have you tried running your program in standalone manner (save it in a `myapp.py`, associate with `pythonw.exe`, doubleclick)?

Answer (score 0):

```
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\idlelib\run.py", 
line 119, in main seq, request = rpc.request_queue.get(block=True, timeout=0.05) 
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\queue.py", line 172,
in get raise Empty queue.Empty
```

these two lines

```
request = rpc.request_queue.get(block=True, timeout=0.05)
raise Empty queue.Empty
```

Suggest you are trying to get data from an empty queue, and an exception is raised. The proper way to deal with this is to put this code in a **try..except** block, catch the exception and deal with it accordingly. 
[Here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) is a decent tutorial on this matter.

```
try:
  ....
  request = rpc.request_queue.get(block=True, timeout=0.05) 
  ....
except Exception,e:
  # this will cath all exceptions derived from the exception class
```

About your second query, I strongly advise you to post a new question instead of bundling them up.

But I'll try and give some advice: self is used to address an instance of a class, it's the current object in use. You can't 'define' self, you use it in a class implementation to tell python that your method is to be used with a specific instance, not the global scope.

```
class demo:
  def __init__(self):
    self.a = 5
  def foo(self):
    self.a = 6
  def global_foo():
    print 'global_foo'
```

Comment: When i type in the 'try' statement you suggested "Exception,e:" comes up as a syntax error, what am i meant to write instead? Cheers

Comment: @Ross Have you written anything after the `except Exception:`, such as `print("Queue Empty")`?

Comment: @Ross please read the tutorial I pointed out. There is no quick fix for your problem because it's conceptual. You have to first understand what's going on, than do something about it.